# Fabric-ca-server affiliation definitions on start (either command line option or environment variables)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I want several other organizations in my network (eg.: 5).
I tried setting affiliations (else 404 errors when communicating with unknown CA's) with environment variables as well as inline command options, neither work.

i.e.: in docker-compose-e2e-template.yaml

```
- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_AFFILIATIONS_ORG4=org4
```

and 
i.e.: in docker-compose-e2e-template.yaml

```
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --affiliations org4.department1 -b admin:adminpw'
```

How can I achieve this without manually exec-ing into the CA's and adding affiliation definitions after the CA's start? 
Surely doing this manually shouldn't be the only way

Answer (score 1):

To quote from [FABRIC_CA_SERVER_AFFILIATIONS in environment variables](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/17550018)

```
since affiliations are arbitrary and hierarchical in nature, it is not possible to specify them as environment variables.
```